# base64_encode a random salt

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I have a method which generates a random salt then I use sha1() on it. How safe would it be to use base64_encode() after I sha1() it? And when I say "safe" I mean, does it have any known collisions or problems with it? I want to use base64_encode() as a means to make it visually different from a sha1() hash but don't know if it makes a hash (in any way) weaker if I do that. Also, is there a better way do what I'm trying to accomplish while staying within PHP4 (yes, that's PHP 4).

A few things: I'm not interested in encryption or that base64_encode() can be decoded. I know it can be decoded.

Comment: It's "safe," why do you want to?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Great, thanks. The OP has the reason why.

Comment: Not really, the op has what you want to do (I want to make it look different) not why you want to.  Why do you want to make it look different?

Comment: I get wanting to make it look different... but base64? Base64 is one of the easiest encoding schemes to identify. If you're worried that someone will crack your SHA1, rest assure that that person will know at first glance what a base64 encoded string looks like.

Comment: Look, I just wanted to find out if I can make the hash look different without collisions. I know it can be decoded on base64, I know a quick glance will reveal what it is, and I know that as the only security measure using base64 is a bad idea... That's NOT what I'm asking.

Comment: So you're not actually trying to solve a problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and call it a day.

**SHA256 Secure Hash Algorithm for PHP 4+**

http://www.nanolink.ca/pub/sha256/

No need for double encoding or encrypting.

Answer (score 2):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is not a [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) algorithm (those are one-way, amongst other things), it's a reversible *[encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoding#Character_encodings)* algorithm - takes one *form* of input and transforms it into another *form* - the contents (and their cryptographical properties) remain the same.

This is similar to other reversible encodings - e.g. writing the hash of string backwards won't affect any of its other properties.

As you see, this won't make the contents any more safe, nor any less safe - it will simply present them differently.

**TL;DR: It's pointless.**